# How to use two views inside scrollview, ImageView below Constraint Layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have this ScrollView Which contains a ConstraintLayout with **wrap_content height**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ----------------
        ----------------
        ----------------
        ----------------

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Currently I am having one ImageView inside ConstraintLayout. which comes at the Bottom when I get the data from server.
But When I am in processing state , I see the image in the middle of the screen. That I want show at the bottom.
I want to place the ImageView at the bottom in such a manner that after getting data from server, it should come at the last after scrolling the screen and in the processing state It should be seen at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `android:fillViewport="true"` for `ScrollView`. this will make child of `ScrollView` (in your case `ConstraintLayout`) fulfil height of `ScrollView` in case when it have smaller height (so probably when you have only one `ImageView` inside). for testing just set some fixed color background for `ConstraintLayout` and check with and without this flag (by default its `false`)

Comment: I Want to put ImageView Below ConstraintLayout, So my ScrollView will have 2 Layouts

Comment: `ScrollView` can't have multiple childs, only one. so just put `ConstraintLayout` and `ImageView` in same parent, e.g. `LinearLayout`, and it should be placed as child of `ScrollView`